# Erro ao configurar o Yowsup para envio de mensagens WhatsApp

Tags: centos, whatsapp, zabbix

Estou tentando instalar o yowsup para envio de mensagems whatsapp no linux, mas quando mando registrar o número ocorre um erro com o python que não tenho ideia de como resolver.

> erro Yowsup python

Meu S.O é o **Centos7.**

Abaixo o erro completo:

```
yowsup-cli registration -r sms -c /etc/zabbix/zap.conf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yowsup-cli", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('yowsup2==2.4', 'yowsup-cli')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 735, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1659, in run_script
    exec(script_code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup2-2.4-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/yowsup-cli", line 323, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup2-2.4-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/yowsup-cli", line 158, in process
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yowsup2-2.4-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/yowsup-cli", line 176, in handleRequestCode
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/yowsup/registration/coderequest.py", line 46, in send
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/yowsup/common/http/warequest.py", line 73, in send
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/yowsup/common/http/warequest.py", line 111, in sendGetRequest
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/yowsup/common/http/warequest.py", line 167, in sendRequest
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1172, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 113] No route to host
```

Comment: Acredito que o erro seja que ele não está conseguindo conectar aos sites externos. Desativa o *firewall* e tenta rodar, antes de tudo tenha certeza de ter rodado `python setup.py install` como *root*.